# Optimizing long on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which changes the text in a certain element on click depending on the text value present in the element at the time the event is fired.

http://jsfiddle.net/TNDhL/

```
$('#left').on('click', function (){
if ($("#textContainer:contains('something')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('third text replacement');
    $('.elsewhere').text('more here');
}
else if ($("#textContainer:contains('third text replacement')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('now the next item');
    $('.elsewhere').text('something new here');
}
else if ($("#textContainer:contains('now the next item')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('new text here');
    $('.elsewhere').text('something else here');
}
else if ($("#textContainer:contains('new text here')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('something');
    $('.elsewhere').text('text here');
}
});

$('#right').on('click', function (){
if ($("#textContainer:contains('something')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('new text here');
    $('.elsewhere').text('something else here');
}
else if ($("#textContainer:contains('new text here')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('now the next item');
    $('.elsewhere').text('something new here');
}
else if ($("#textContainer:contains('now the next item')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('third text replacement');
    $('.elsewhere').text('more here');
}
else if ($("#textContainer:contains('third text replacement')").length) {
    $('#textContainer').text('something');
    $('.elsewhere').text('text here');
}
});
```

Please see fiddle above for working version.

I'd like to find a way to make this more manageable in order to make extending this further easier. Is there a better way to handle this case? Condensing this into a function and using variables to store the value of #textContainer would be more ideal. Any suggestions?

Comment: i'd suggest to post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use a `text -> replacements` map or a simple array to store all the texts and rotate over it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, was unaware of codereview.stackexchange.com I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect case for a closure which can track your progress with a simple counter..  Could look something like this:

```
var myTextRotator = (function () {
    var myPhraseArray = ["first phrase", "second phrase"],
        counter = 0;
    return {
       clickLeft: function () {
           counter -= 1;
           return myPhraseArray[counter]; //return array item or do your processing here
       },
       clickRight: function () {
           counter += 1;
           return myPhraseArray[counter]; //return array item or do your processing here
       }
    };
}());
```

Tie the `clickLeft` and `clickRight` methods to an jQuery `.on()`.  May have to add a conditional in there so the counter doesn't go below 0 or above the array length.

You would use this like:

```
$(".left").on("click", function () {
    myTextRotator.clickLeft();
});

$(".right").on("click", function () {
    myTextRotator.clickRight();
});
```